# Visual Studio 2015 not importing fonts and colors from 2013 properly

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to import my fonts and colors from Vs 2013 to Vs 2015.

To do that I go in Vs 2013, `Tools`, `Import and Export Settings`, `Export Selected Environment Settings` and inside it I check only `Options`, `Environment`, `Fonts and Colors`.

Well. When I import it to Vs 2015 most of it works fine, but there are some tags that apparently have changed from 2013 to 2015, for example:

In 2013 the tag for classes names is `User Types`, but in 2015 the tag has changed to `User Types - Classes`, therefore the 2013 colors for this tag is not replicated in 2015, keeping the tag with the default color of 2015.

Besides this specific tag there are many others that had some changes in the name (and some new tags too).

Is there any tool that can fix that or migrate these configs?

Answer (score -4):

[Visual Studio 2015 Color Theme Editor](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6f4b51b6-5c6b-4a81-9cb5-f2daa560430b) is the tool to import and upgrade themes from Visual Studio 2013

Comment: I've tried to install it here, but I couldn't find an option to import a config file from Vs 2013. It only import themes (to change the entire UI), it doesn't import configuration files apparently. I've even installed it in 2013 to try to generate a theme there, but the focus of the extension is more about the UI (borders, menus, footer) than the code itself.

Comment: "Fonts and color" have nothing to do with the theme.